# How do I stop propagation when click on anchor in dropdown in angular 7

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

when i click on dropdown menu it,s show list of all nested menu but when i click on nested link it close the dropdown list i want that do not close the dropdown list i am using angular 7 this is my menu

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav" >

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-truncate collapsed" href="#submenu1" data- 
       toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1"
        aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-file-alt"></i> <span class="d- 
        none d-sm-inline">Contracts </span></a>
      <div class="collapse" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="false">

        <ul class="flex-column nav" >

         <li class="nav-item" ><a class="nav-link py-1" 
        (click)="navPropigation($event)" 
        routerLink="/contracts/supplier">Supplier Contract </a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-1" 
           routerLink="/contracts/client">Client Contracts</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-1" data-toggle="modal" 
           data-target="#exampleModal">Create Contracts</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

i have use these line of code in component.ts file but not working

```
navPropigation($event)
{
$event.stopPropagation();
}
```

i have tried so many other thing but nothing is work for me

Comment: Could you please reformat your code so that it is readable for a human? And maybe reduce the code to the relevant parts. Maybe you could even create an executable example at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Have you tried, $event.preventDefault() instead? or $event.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: yes i also tried preventDefault() as well but not working

Comment: Correct me if am wrong you want submenu active when clicked. please read https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: yes you are right i know about the routerLinkActive it,s use to apply active class and i want that when anchor clicked do not close the dropdown menu